# "String or binary data would be truncated" during INSERT INTO

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have total of 22025 records to be insert from the select list. The error "String or binary data would be truncated" prompt when i execute the below script. While if i add in some where clause to the select list to reduce the number of records to be insert in once, e.g. 10000 records for 1st insertion and 12025 records for 2nd insertion, no error prompt.
I've checked the length of each field, not exceeding the destination columns' length.
Please advise. Thanks!

```
INSERT INTO [BWX] 
SELECT PK1.STRING_VALUE,PK2.STRING_VALUE,PK3.STRING_VALUE,PK4.STRING_VALUE,
       2000010, BW_ROW.ID AS BW_ROW_ID, BW_ROW.SEQUENCE_NUMBER, 
       0 AS UPDATE_FLAG, 0 AS DELETE_FLAG, BW_ROW.IS_ACTIVE 
FROM BW_CELL AS PK1, BW_COLUMN AS PK1COL, BW_CELL AS PK2, BW_COLUMN AS PK2COL, 
     BW_CELL AS PK3, BW_COLUMN AS PK3COL, BW_CELL AS PK4, BW_COLUMN AS PK4COL, 
     BW_COLUMN AS PK9COL, BW_ROW 
WHERE PK1.BW_ROW_ID = BW_ROW.ID AND PK1.PTN_KEY = 100 
      AND PK1.BW_COLUMN_ID = PK1COL.ID AND PK1COL.NAME = 'key_1' 
      AND PK2.BW_ROW_ID = BW_ROW.ID AND PK2.PTN_KEY = 100 
      AND PK2.BW_COLUMN_ID = PK2COL.ID AND PK2COL.NAME = 'key_2' 
      AND PK3.BW_ROW_ID = BW_ROW.ID AND PK3.PTN_KEY = 100 
      AND PK3.BW_COLUMN_ID = PK3COL.ID AND PK3COL.NAME = 'key_3' 
      AND PK4.BW_ROW_ID = BW_ROW.ID AND PK4.PTN_KEY = 100 
      AND PK4.BW_COLUMN_ID = PK4COL.ID AND PK4COL.NAME = 'key_4' 
      AND BW_ROW.BW_TBL_ID = 2000010 AND BW_ROW.IS_ACTIVE = 1 AND BW_ROW.TX_ID > -1 
      AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT [BWX_ROW@DEVICE_FORECAST].BW_ROW_ID 
                       FROM [BWX_ROW@DEVICE_FORECAST] 
                       WHERE BW_ROW.ID = [BWX_ROW@DEVICE_FORECAST].BW_ROW_ID )
```

Comment: It means some of your data is too big for the column you're trying to put it into.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It's not clear what exactly you'd like us to do with that mess of SQL you dumped here. There's absolutely nothing we can tell you that isn't in the error message - you have a value in your data being inserted that is larger than the column it's being inserted into. We don't have access to the data you're importing to tell you where the problem is; you'll have to figure that out yourself. Good luck.

Comment: Wow, old-school joins in a wall of code. Fun fun! Can you let us know whether the destination table, with the terrible, terrible name `[BWX_ROW@DEVICE]`, has columns of the same name as the output? Including the column names in the `INSERT` statement might have made is easier for us to generate a comparison script dynamically for you that would let you know which column(s) are likely candidates for the source of the error. Without that, well, like Ken said, good luck.

Answer (score 1):

To help troubleshoot this you may want to run the [`LEN`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx) function on each of your columns and compare it to the schema in order to figure out which one is causing the problem:

Without re-posting the entire SQL statment in your question...

```
SELECT LEN(PK1.STRING_VALUE), LEN(PK2.STRING_VALUE), LEN(PK3.STRING_VALUE)
-- ...and so on
```

This is definitely one of the most unhelpful error messages SQL Server generates since it gives you almost nowhere to start.

Comment: Hi, i did do a compare, but it passed, not exceeding the destination columns length. I'm able to insert all records while split into 2 insert script.

Comment: Any idea what happened? Thanks!

Comment: @thszone any triggers on that table?

Answer (score 1):

Not only do you need to use LEN for the column, but also DATALENGTH.
LEN will append a trim on the column where as [DATALENGTH](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486.aspx) will not...

As far as isolating the row that's invalid -- if you can create a separate table in your schema to work with, you could always try `INSERT TOP 100000 ....` into the new table and see if you can figure out where it breaks.  Once you figure out the row number, that gives you a good place to start looking.